# How can I make axis x vertical so the long names of countries become understandable in the plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

The name of the countries are long and are on top of each other in the x labels, how can I make it readable?

[image]

```
ggplot(results, aes(x = Nationality, horiz=TRUE)) +
  theme_solarized() +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(y = "Number of Medals", 
       title = "Number of Medals by Country")
```

Comment: use a service like imagebin to share images.

Comment: use  +theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=90,hjust=1,vjust=0.5))

Comment: use `coord_flip()` to make it horizontal bar charts.

Comment: @XeroSmith, `<sarcasm>`what ... you don't have access to Takeshi's desktop? Let me get that for you ... ;-)`</sarcasm>`  (... Takeshi, no of course I don't have access ... but it's sometimes funny how often we forget about small things like privacy and computer security when asking questions on SO)

Comment: @JonSpring that worked to put it horizontally but still the text is messy and can't see it well

Comment: You'll have to be more descriptive for us to be any help.

Comment: @JonSpring https://imagebin.ca/v/4jOc5uIDQBGd here is an image maybe it helps convey my problem

Comment: https://imagebin.ca/v/4jOc5uIDQBGd here is an image maybe it helps convey my problem @XeroSmith

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to stackoverflow. Here are some suggestions on how you can deal with the many values. In both methods, I am using the `forcats` library within the `tidyverse`. You can read more about it here: https://r4ds.had.co.nz/factors.html

First, some fake data & replicating your problem

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <-
  mpg %>% 
  arrange(manufacturer) %>% 
  mutate(
    n = row_number(),
    vehicle = paste(year, manufacturer, model)
  ) %>% 
  uncount(n)


# this replicates your problem
ggplot(df, aes(vehicle)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

## Option 1: consolidate

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(
    vehicle = # making heavy use of forcats here
      fct_lump(vehicle, 35) %>% # keep only the 35 most frequent values, others in "Other" category
      fct_infreq() %>% # order them by frequency
      fct_rev() #reverse the order
  ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(vehicle)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

## Option 2: facet

Someone may have a more elegant way of getting these groups but I use this method quite a bit

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(
    vehicle = # similar methods to earlier
      fct_infreq(vehicle) %>% 
      fct_rev(),
    num_fct = as.integer(vehicle), # generates a number for each factor
    facet = (max(num_fct)-num_fct) %/% 20 # will make groups of 20, but they need to be in descending order within each facet
  ) %>%
  ggplot(aes(vehicle)) +
  geom_bar() +
  coord_flip() +
  facet_wrap(~facet, scales = "free_y", nrow = 1) +
  theme(
    strip.background = element_blank(),
    strip.text = element_blank()
  )
```

[image]

Hope this helps.